# Mostrar un Select List Multiple con datos precargados de la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buen día tengo el siguiente problema

Del mi controlador hago una consulta a mi base de datos la cual me trae una lista con {Key,Value}
y por medio de un viewgbag lo mando a un DropDownList de la siguiente manera

SoftwareId es mi viewbag

`@Html.DropDownList("SoftwareId", (SelectList)ViewBag.SoftwareId, new { @id = "SoftwareId", multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control chosen-select " })`

todo funciona bien pero la lista me la trae como opciones de selección

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber si ay alguna manera de que la lista me la muestre datos precargados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se muestra en la imagen

Comment: Desconozco `ASP`, pero puedes agregarle el atributo `selected="selected"` a cada uno de los `option`.

Comment: es lo que he estado intentando pero no encuentro como

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar a la propiedad lo siguiente

```
<asp:ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="" name="" runat="server" class="js-select2 form-control" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:ListBox>
```

A mi me funciono!

Comment: No olvides explicar los cambios que has hecho. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.